# R: Directly "Feed" Results into an IF STATEMENT

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. I have the following example - there are two data frames (height_quantiles and test):

```
> height_quantiles
  salary_type quant_80
1           A 3.752192
2           B 3.713571
3           C 4.117180

> str(height_quantiles)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ salary_type: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
 $ quant_80   : Named num  3.75 3.71 4.12
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "80%" "80%" "80%"
```

and

```
> head(test)
       salary     height salary_type
701  1.358904  1.6148796           A
702 -2.702212  1.0604070           A
703  1.534527 -4.0957218           A
704  5.594247  5.7373110           B
705 -1.823547  5.5808484           A
706  7.949913 -0.2021635           C

str(test)
'data.frame':   300 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ salary     : num  1.36 -2.7 1.53 5.59 -1.82 ...
 $ height     : num  1.61 1.06 -4.1 5.74 5.58 ...
 $ salary_type: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 1 1 2 1 3 2 1 2 3 ...
```

I am trying to write the following code :

```
test$height_pred = as.numeric(ifelse(test$salary_type == "A", height_quantiles[1,1], ifelse(test$salary_type == "B", height_quantiles[2,1], height_quantiles[3,1])))
```

But this returning values of "test$height_pred " as "1,2,3" . But I would like it to return values corresponding to the height_quantiles frame such as "3.75, 3.71 , 4.12".

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract data from the second column i.e `height_quantiles[1,2]`, `height_quantiles[2,2]` etc. Right now, you are doing it from the first column.

Also a better approach would be to use a join or `match`.

```
test$height_pred <- height_quantiles$quant_80[match(test$salary_type, height_quantiles$salary_type)]
```

Or

```
merge(test, height_quantiles)
```

Comment: @ Ronak Shah: thank you for your answer! I will have to remember this "match" command in R. It looks pretty useful!